# why am I only getting one last entry written to file

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing file to disk but before i write i collect all the items from QListWidget to text variable with each line separated by "\n" but instead of getting all the lines i get only last line:

```
def makeBatFile(self):
    text=""
    for each in xrange(self.listWidget.count()):
        text="echo [Task Id:%s]\n" % each
        text=text+ self.listWidget.item(each).text() +"\n"
        print text
    self.writeBatFile("batch",text)
```

although the print inside the for loop prints all the line but i cannot make the call to writeBatfile method from within the for loop because it will try to write the file the number of items in the list when i want all the list items to be written in one file...

```
def writeBatFile(self,do="single",task=None):
    self.task=task
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    buildCrntTime=str(now.hour) +"_" + str(now.minute)
    selected=str(self.scnFilePath.text())
    quikBatNam=os.path.basename(selected).split(".")[0]+"_"+buildCrntTime+".bat"
    if do !="batch":
        self.batfiletoSave=os.path.join(os.path.split(selected)[0],quikBatNam)
        self.task = str(self.makeBatTask())
    else:
        self.batfiletoSave=os.path.join(self.batsDir,buildCrntTime+".bat")
    try:
        writeBat=open(self.batfiletoSave,'w')
        writeBat.write(self.task)
        self.execRender()
    except: pass
    finally: writeBat.close()
```

What am I doing wrong while building the content to be passed to writeBatFile method?

Comment: Don't use `except: pass`, you'll hide any problems that arise during writing and will make it hard to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing over your text variable in each loop of the for loop. You should append each line to the text variable:

```
def makeBatFile(self):
    text=""
    for each in xrange(self.listWidget.count()):
        text += "echo [Task Id:%s]\n" % each
        text += self.listWidget.item(each).text() +"\n"
        print text
    self.writeBatFile("batch",text)
```

the += operator is a shortcut for:

```
text = text + othertext
```

This way you are appending the string to the text variable in each iteration of the loop instead of reassigning the variable to the new string.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration you're redefining `text` with `text=` so the value from the previous loop iteration is no longer referenced, So only the value of `text` in the final iteration of the loop is passed to `writeBatFile`

One solution would be to create a list in `makeBatFile` and append the `text` variable to it in each iteration. Then this could be passed into `writeBatFile` and written to the file by passing it to `.writelines`

Answer (score 0):

There is the bug: In each loop you do

```
text="echo [Task Id:%s]\n" % each
```

which dumps whatever `text` hold in the previous iteration. Instead, do

```
text += "echo [Task Id:%s]\n" % each
```